# Parsing table rows with beautiful soup

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse through this html and get the 53.1 and 41.7 values. I'm not quite sure how to do it.

I've been trying to do it using Beautiful Soup

Any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Please post the code as text and not as image.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
r = urllib.urlopen('url/to/open').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r)
print type(soup)
```

-OR-

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = raw_input("Enter a website to extract the URL's from: ")
r  = requests.get("http://" +url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

notice the .find_all() method. try exploring all helper methods of beautifulsoup. good luck.